# How to make a replacement over the webs loaded in a Webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview, chromium

I'm implementing an app using a webview. For the urls loaded in the webview I'd need to perform a replacement over the html code loaded in the url.

How can I do this in a efficient way?

Explanation: I need to replace an specific script script from the source:

In example: I want to

```
<html>
    <script> SCRIPT A</script>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</html>
```

I want to display the user this other

```
<html>
    <script> SCRIPT B</script>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: could you be a little clearer? do you need to replace parts of the url or parts of the page you are loading? and do you need to replace whole blocks at a time or is this on a word-by-word-basis? also, are you looking for hooks into the android delegate system, or are you looking for suggestions as to what algorithm to use?

Comment: I updated my question, please check it out

Comment: if i not mistaken, you want to replace current web js script to your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `shouldInterceptRequest` of `WebViewClient`. See the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

The general form would be something like this (untested):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
        if (you_want_to_intercept) {
            /*return custom WebresourceResponse here*/
        } else {
            /*call superclass*/
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http request to get the HTML page as a String, then use something like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to find and replace the script, and use [WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to load the HTML content into the WebView.